# Gradle Dependencies and intelliJ idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I've been trying to integrate my multi-project gradle build script in idea.

It does more than it's supposed to. I've had to make changes in order to appease idea, and the result is a little annoying.

My multi-project build was originally task-dependency based, but to get idea to recognize the second module and compile properly, I had to include a

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":B")
}
```

This makes gradle set the :B:jar task as a dependency for :A:compile from the command line. I don't want this. I want idea to recognize project(":B") as a dependency for project(":A"), WITHOUT creating these kinds of automatic dependencies (like jar).

I'm also using the idea plugin, though I haven't found a field that fixes my problem.

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm sort of able to do this if I manually set the dependency in idea for the project(":B") module while excluding it from the code; however, refreshing gradle resets it. This needs to be automated and the default setting.

Comment: What kind of dependency do you want? if it's just task from project A depends on task from project B, then just add that dependency to the task from A directly.

Comment: I do. But idea's compile fails because it parses the gradle file to set up its structure. So, if I don't have the dependencies {} block, my idea compiles the modules out of order, and I get errors..

Comment: Again, what does Project A need from Project B exactly? right now it sounds like A needs compiled code from B, but without the compile dependency its not getting the classes and therefore throwing errors.

Comment: Yes, that is what happening. I compile code in A, then B uses that. In order to automate that process in idea, I have to set a project dependency, which causes gradle to set a jar task dependency between the two projects, which I dislike.

Comment: sounds like this might be a bigger problem than just the task dependencies, since those task dependencies are exactly what you would want if the projects depended on each other. If you'd like you can join https://discord.gg/Aspchc6 and answer some questions so that i can get a better understanding.